# Navigate to specific page after a given time of user inactivity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, components

I'm trying to navigate or to show Home page component in React application after a given time period of user inactivity.

I have working `automaticRefresh` function which detects idle time by DOM events and reloads application after 2 minutes. Function is called in *index.js* file.

***automaticRefresh***

```
export default function () {
  let timer;

  window.onload = timerReset;
  document.onkeypress = timerReset;
  document.onmousemove = timerReset;
  document.onmousedown = timerReset;
  document.ontouchstart = timerReset;
  document.onclick = timerReset;
  document.onscroll = timerReset;
  document.onkeypress = timerReset;

  function timerElapsed() {
    window.location.reload();
    // Navigate or show Home page component
  };

  function timerReset() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(timerElapsed, 2 * 60 * 1000); // 2 mins
  }
}
```

As you can see in `timerElapsed` function I set page reload and it's working fine, but I had a new task to change that could navigate to Home page.
Already in App container I have all my components logic which `Statement` or `Home` component to show.

***App container***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// Components
import Header from './components/Header';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Statement from './components/Statement';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const statement = this.props.statement !== null;

    return (
      <div>
        <Header />

        { statement ? <Statement /> : <Home /> }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So how to show Home component after period of inactivity in React without Router?

Answer (score 0):

I posted a response but realized after that you don't want to use a router.  In which case, you do window.location = "http://yoururl.com".

This will only work if it's a real destination and not a react route.  If it is a react route you want to hit, you need a router.

Comment: Already tried. It's working, but also reloads page and in my case don't need that. Application must have single page app feeling, so i think solution will be to show or hide Home page component in some conditions. Router will be also good solution, but i have requirement to do without it.